# Give the sum of a list from the second index while creating a unique list Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, set

I have the following list of lists:

```
wall_type_list = [['wall', 0.3], ['wall',0.7], ['tile', 0.5],['tile', 0.4]]
```

the first item of the list is always a string, the second item always a float.  They are always containing two items. My aim is to create a new list which sums the second item containing the floats while creating a new list with unique strings:

so the desired output should be this:

```
wall_list = [['wall',1.0],['tile',0.9]]
```

What I tried to do so far is creating a new list containing unique strings with `set`

```
wall_list = []
    for i in wall_type_list:
       wall_list.append(i[0])

unique_wall_list = list(set(wall_list))
```

this creates:

```
unique_wall_list = ['wall', 'tile']
```

I think now I should compare the list `unique_wall_list` with the `wall_type_list`, if the first item of the `wall_type_list` matches with the first item of the `wall_type_list` it should return a sum of the second items. I am stuck on how to do this, with a method, a dictionary or make a method.

I tried this so far:

```
for j in unique_wall_list:
    for i in wall_type_list:
        if i[0] == j:
            sum_list.append(i[1])   
            wall_dict[j] = sum_list
```

it returns: `{'wall': [0.3, 0.7, 0.5, 0.4], 'tile': [0.3, 0.7, 0.5, 0.4]}`

but my aim is to have this returned: `{'wall': [0.3, 0.7], 'tile': [0.5, 0.4]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

wall_type_list = [['wall', 0.3], ['wall',0.7], ['tile', 0.5],['tile', 0.4]]
result = defaultdict(int)
result_aslist = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in wall_type_list:
    result[k] += v
    result_aslist[k].append(v)

print(result)
print(result_aslist)
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'wall': 1.0, 'tile': 0.9})
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'wall': [0.3, 0.7], 'tile': [0.5, 0.4]})
```